# Laravel - Redirect to page thrgough javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, web

So, what I want to do is this:
I have a search page, which displays several products. This is how I call this view:

```php
public function show()
  {
    $products = App\Product::paginate(20);
    return view('pages.search')->with('products', $products);
  }
```

In this page, I have some filters like brand, price, etc. When I click the 'apply filters' button, I send an ajax request.

```js
function sendApplyFiltersRequest(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //get info from checkboxes
  sendAjaxRequest('post', 'search/filter', {brand: 1, price: 100}, searchFilterHanlder);
}
```

which calls this function:

```js
function sendAjaxRequest(method, url, data, handler) {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open(method, url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  request.addEventListener('load', handler);
  request.send(encodeForAjax(data));
}
```

the request, with all the information, is sent to my 'search/filter' route, which leads to this function:

```php
public function filterResults(Request $request)
  {
    $brands = $request->brands;
    $minPrice = $request->minPrice;
    //more stuff about the filters
  }
```

And now I need that function to be able to redirect to the page again. So it would be something like:

```php
public function filterResults(Request $request)
  {
    $brands = $request->brands;
    $minPrice = $request->minPrice;
    $products = App\Product::all()->where('price', '<', $minPrice);
    return redirect('pages.search')->with('products', $products);
  }
```

the ajax response handler is the following:

```js
function searchFilterHanlder() {
  if (this.status != 200) {
    alert("Failed to filter results :'(");
  }
  //do stuff
}
```

How can I do something like this?

Note: I can't do it the way I'm showing you, because I make the ajax request through a javascript function (in my search.js file), and so what the filterResults returns will go to that javascript function, and won't actually redirect right away.

Comment: You have to redirect your response function in ajax call

Comment: How so? Can you explain further? I edited my question to show the call for ajax function. @A.ANoman

Comment: Add your ajax call function

Comment: I did, check it out in the question @A.ANoman

Comment: Oh. Iam sorry. Because I don't see any success function in ajax call.

Comment: Added it now, what should i put in the success function? @A.ANoman

Comment: It has been a long while since I've used Javascript or Laravel but wouldn't a good old fashioned Javascript redirection work? ` function redirect()
{
  window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
  console.log("Redirecting to w3Schools");
}` - You would have to send whatever information along though.

Comment: @Phoenix2105 the thing is, when I redirect to this view, I have to provide the products arrray. Like I showed in the first function. How can I do that with the redirect you're showing?

Comment: @Pheonix2105 just tagging you

Comment: Where are you redirecting this to? There are a few ways to send data along with a request, it depends how the other server accepts them, thanks for the tag, forgot to check back :)

Comment: So I see Laravel has a function for this already

    return redirect()->away('http://bla.com?bla=bla');


Assuming I wanted to redirect a passed in string to google to do a websearch, assuming you can get the string into the function (which im sure you can!) you could do 

    return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com/search?q=' . $myVarString);

You can extend this for other parameters, I would think Laravel has some kind of query builder for this, I'll have a look.

Comment: Slight correction - PHP has a function for this! http_build_query (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)